# Javascript: Loop through class and push the inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem with pushing some input values to an `array`. I have a `div` with a class `optiondiv` that can be cloned. This div has some table rows with some input fields as follows:

```
<div class="optiondiv">
    <table class="tableOptions">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="title">
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" class="position">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="input">
                    <option value="1">Drop-down</option>
                    <option value="2">Radio Buttons</option>
                    <option value="3">Checkbox</option>
                    <option value="4">Multiple Select</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="required"> Required?
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get all the input fields of the option, for each option and then push them to an array. The problem is that there's no 'split' between each option. If I use `console.log();`, the values will be printed like this: `[Doors, 1, Windows, 5]` but what I really want is

```
[0][Doors, 1]
[1][Windows, 5]
```

This is de code that I'm using:

```
$('.generateString').click(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.optiondiv').each(function(){
            var arrText = new Array();

            $('input[type=text]').each(function ()
            {
               if($(this).val() != ''){
                   // arrText.push('nietleeg');
                   arrText.push($(this).val());
                }
            })
            console.log(arrText);
        })

    });
```

Happy coding!

Comment: There is no class 'generateString' in your html

Comment: There is, Im not pasting my whole html cause that could be difficult to read.

Comment: try: ` arrText.push([$(this).val()]);`

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or something

Comment: @KoenvandeSande in `[Doors, 1, Windows, 5] ` what is `Doors` and `Windows` ??

Comment: Doors and Windows is the input you get from title.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/89IXO maybey that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, instead of

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function ()
```

you need to use this for fetching input elements inside each .optiondiv

```
$(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function ()
```

And for your requirement, just define the array variable outside and create associative array inside the each loop like below

```
$('.generateString').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var arrText = new Array();
    $('.optiondiv').each(function(i) {
        if (typeof arrText[i] == "undefined")
            arrText[i] = new Array();

        $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
                // arrText.push('nietleeg');
                arrText[i].push($(this).val());
            }
        })
        console.log(arrText[i]);
    })

    console.log(arrText);

});
```

Comment: Works! Thanks! But is there a way i can add an index to the array, so that i can loop through those arrays aswell?

Comment: sorry not getting what you are asking, can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, I have these values now but they dont have an index right?

Comment: means key,value pair you need?

Comment: Yeah, think so.

Comment: for that you need to take objects instead of arrays i.e [{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar"}, {...}] you need something like this right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138614/discussion-between-vara-prasad-and-koen-van-de-sande).